# Is there a way to programmatically identify the clear button on mobiles by using j2me?

Tags: java, java-me, mobile, nokia

Is there a way to programmatically identify the clear button on mobiles like nokia, sony ericsson, LG, Samsung? Some mobiles having clear ("C") button and some mobiles doesn't have. I want to identify the clear button while my application running time. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Dogbane's answer is a good starting point...

another trick is to [observe](http://www.j2meforums.com/wiki/index.php/Canvas_Keycodes) that -8 is a common keyCode to represent Clear.  So if you call [`canvas.getKeyName(-8)`](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Canvas.html#getKeyName%28int%29), and no `IllegalArgumentException` is thrown, you know that there **is** a delete key.

So there's no exact science on this, but a combination of these two approaches should work most of the time.

Comment: Its only possible on KeyPressed event. Is it possible on application startup? that means initial of loading my application.

Comment: you can instantiate a canvas and call getKeyName() whenever you like

Answer (score 1):

You can call `getKeyName`. For example:

```
public void keyPressed(int keyCode) {
    if(getKeyName(keyCode).toUpperCase().indexOf("CLEAR") >= 0){
        //clear was pressed
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, might work some of the time but remember there's no guarantee what the key name will be...  could be "C", "DELETE", anything...